# Xamarin android project is not getting deployed

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 2017 on windows 10 desktop (64 bit)
this is a new installation of Xamarin plug-in. and I am just running my application using android emulator.
and xamarin android project failing in deploy with below error

```
1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore 
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for 
Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg 
SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\App5.App5-Signed-
Unaligned.apk C:\Users\
<Username>\source\repos\App5\App5\obj\Debug\android\bin\App5.App5.apk 
androiddebugkey 
1>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not 
timestamped.Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate 
this 
jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2048-01-09) or 
after any future revocation date.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-
tools\25.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\
<UserName>\source\repos\App5\App5\bin\Debug\App5.App5-Signed-
Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\App5.App5-Signed.apk" 
1>"zipalign.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
```

please note I am using `android SDK` build tools version 25.0.3
registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools]` pointing to correct path where android SDK reside.
also if zipalign command executed separately on command prompt doesn't give any error.

Comment: Could you please try it again in an empty blank project? If the problem persists. please try reinstalling the android SDK.

Comment: Yes. I tried with several blank projects. and also tried to install android SDK. zipalign.exe is failing with a particular exit code. even after using another version of android build tools same error is thrown. can somebody please help

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Solution, Properties, Configuration Properties and then tick the project you would like to deploy.